# sIFR removes all content on page?

Tags: html, sifr

I have a really weird error. When I use sIFR to replace a single h1 element, everything else on the page disappears. It's really odd. I don't get any javascript errors.

If I edit out the sIFR.activate function in he sifr-config, everything is displayed normally...

This is my code... HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<title>sIFR test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sifr.css" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css">

<script src="js/sifr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/sifr-config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Dette er en overskrift</h1>

<ul class="menu">
<li class="parent active"><a href="#"><span>Main Menu Item 1</span></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Menu Item 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Menu Item 2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Menu Item 3</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Menu Item 4</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Menu Item 5</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="parent"><a href="#"><span>Main Menu Item 2</span></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Menu Item 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Menu Item 2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Menu Item 3</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Menu Item 4</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Menu Item 5</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Main Menu Item 3</span></a></li>
<li class="parent"><a href="#"><span>Main Menu Item 4</span></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Menu Item 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Sub Menu Item 2</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#"><span>Main Menu Item 5</span></a></li>
</ul>
<br class="clearfloat" />
</body>
</html>
```

sifr-config.js:

```
var helvetica57 = { src: 'sifr/helveticaNeue57Condensed.swf' };

var helvetica67 = { src: 'sifr/helveticaNeue67Medium.swf' };

sIFR.activate(helvetica57, helvetica67);

sIFR.replace(helvetica67, {

  selector: 'h1',
  css: '.sIFR-root {color: #000000; }'

});
```

You can see an example here: www.runemadsen.com/innovation/sifr

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this? It is happening to me as well.

Answer (score 1):

You've added the following CSS:

```
.sIFR-active {
  font-family: Verdana;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

This hides the entire `<html>` element.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, basically the problem was calling activate from within another function or event. Moved it out and no problem.